# Passing data from controller to laravel nested view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a page system in Laravel - where I pass data from controller to view.

```
$this->data['title'] = $row->title;
$this->data['breadcrumb'] = $row->bc;
```

Now I passed it as follows:

```
return View::make('Themes.Page', $this->data);
```

In the view file, I access the data as follows:

```
{{$breadcrumb}}
```

What I am trying to do now is to pass this data in nested views:

```
$this->layout->nest('content',$page, $this->data);
```

(Content is the {{content}} in the view which will be replaced with $page contents. I want to pass the $this->data just as before but now I get an error:

Variable breadcrumb not defined.

> Note: Laravel Version 4.2 $this->layout is set in constructor to a
>   template file (Themes.Page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to pass any separate data to your partial page(breadcrumb)

### controller page

```
$this->data['title'] = $row->title;
$this->data['breadcrumb'] = $row->bc;

return View::make('idea.show',array("data"=>$this->data));
```

### main view page

```
<div>
<h1>here you can print data passed from controller  {{$data['title']}}</h1>
@include('partials.breadcrumb')
</div>
```

### your partial file

```
<div>
<h1>here also you can print data passed from controller {{$data['title']}}</h1>
<ul>
<li>....<li>
<li>....<li>
</ul>
</div>
```

for more information on this you can check following links http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template  or watch this video https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/13

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data as follows

```
return View::make('Themes.Page')->with(array(
            'data'=>$this->data));
```

or (since you're passing only 1 variable)

```
return View::make('Themes.Page')->with('data', $this->data);
```

and further you can pass it on to nested views as by referencing $data

Comment: Thank you. But my question is about Nested Views.

Comment: Yes when you pass it with a variable name, you can that name across all your nested views. Just how explained by Rameez.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataForNestedView = ['breadcrumb' => $row->bc];

return View::make('Themes.Page', $this->data)->nest('content', 'page.content', $dataForNestedView);
```

In the Themes.Page view render nested view:

```
<div>
   {{ $content }} <!-- There will be nested view -->
</div>
```

And in the nested page.content view you can call:

```
<div>
  {{ $breadcrumb }}
</div>
```

*div tag is only for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after intense search, I figured out that there was a bug in the Laravel version 4.2 I was using.
Laravel 5 works.
For laravel 4.2, a better option would be to pass array of data objects using `View::share('data',$objectarray)` while passing the data from controller.

Thanks everyone for help